# Importing VPCGatewayAttachment from another template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, elastic-ip

I have a network stack that contains an InternetGateway, that is attached to a VPC via a VPCGatewayAttachment element.

I have an application stack where I have an EIP and it should Depend on the VPCGatewayAttachment which currently looks like this:

```
"MyEIP": {
  "Type": "AWS::EC2::EIP",
  "DependsOn": [
    { "Fn::ImportValue" : {"Fn::Sub": "${NetworkStackName}-GatewayAttachment" } }
  ],
}
```

However I get a template error which says that every DependsOn value must be a string. So how can I import this value?

Comment: Did you export it in the stack you try to import from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use the [`DependsOn`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html) attribute on the [`AWS::EC2::EIP`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-eip.html) resource in your application stack, because the [`AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-vpc-gateway-attachment.html) resource is being created in a separate network stack. This is noted in the EIP resource's [`Domain`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-eip.html#cfn-ec2-eip-domain) property:

> Note
>
> If you define an Elastic IP address and associate it with a VPC **that is defined in the same template**, you must declare a dependency on the VPC-gateway attachment by using the `DependsOn` attribute on this resource.

When the VPC is defined in a separate template you don't need to explicitly declare any dependency. As long as the application stack gets deleted before the network stack, the EIP will get deleted before the VPC-gateway attachment.

More generally, declaring a `DependsOn` between stacks is never necessary. Since you can't delete a stack if another stack references one of its outputs, using `Fn::ImportValue` to create a cross-stack reference creates a dependency that the stack containing the reference must be deleted before the stack being referenced.

Comment: it might not be necessary, but the reason this doesn't work is that the DependsOn needs a string, not some function ;)

Comment: Yes, the question already acknowledged that every DependsOn value must be a string. What was asked was "So how can I import this value?" (my answer: you don't need to and it's never necessary, and here's why).

Answer (score -1):

As the docs say (and you have read), the `DependsOn` attribute accepts a String (or list of String).

This is meant **literally**, in that, you are NOT meant to use the CloudFormation `Fn` or `Ref` functions to insert some value there, rather you just insert the name of the CloudFormation resource, exactly like you have it in your template.

So, your template should read something like:

```
"MyEIP": {
  "Type": "AWS::EC2::EIP",
  "DependsOn": [
    "MyGatewayAttachment"
  ],
}
```

, where `MyGatewayAttachment` is the **name** of the corresponding CloudFormation resource in your template.

If you take another look at the [examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html) on the official docs, you'll see that this is the way it's done in all the examples.

Answer (score -2):

You have brackets around your import statement. Which in [JSON](http://www.json.org/) means that object is going to be an array and not a string. Remove those brackets and you will get past this error.

```
"MyEIP": {
  "Type": "AWS::EC2::EIP",
  "DependsOn": { "Fn::ImportValue": { "Fn::Sub": "${NetworkStackName}-GatewayAttachment" } }
}
```

Comment: Depends On accepts a string and a list of string, so thats not the issue